# Highlight parent path to the root

Tags: javascript, d3.js, path, tree, highlight

I try to highlight paths from the node I have my mouse on to the root node by changing the fill of the nodes and links. I am using a Radial Tidy Tree from Mike's on [Block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550).

I tried the `node.ancestors()`, but this is not recognized as a function.
When I try to create a variable and put `node.parent` in it, or use `d3.select(this.parentNode)` it does not work either.

I found on a Google Groups someone trying to do the contrary, and Mike Bostock [told them](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/Cw94911QIB4/E818lrkTa_AJ) the problem is coming from his tree data.

I used the method Mike gave and it worked perfectly:

```
node.on("mouseover", function(p) {

  //color the links
  link.filter(function(d) {
    for (d = d.source; d; d = d.parent) {
      if (d === p) return true;

      }
  }).style("stroke","black");

  //color the nodes 
  node.filter(function(d) {
    while(d = d.parent){
      if(d === p) return true ;
    }
  }).style("fill","red");

});
```

It changes the color, and I also did the contrary with `mouseout`. 
But I cannot configure it with the opposite direction (node to parent to root), can someone help me do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a slightly different approach to get nodes going from child to root. One option that comes to mind is gathering a list of all the nodes in the chain:

```
node.on("mouseover", function(p) {

    var nodes = [];
    nodes.push(p);

    while(p.parent) {
        p = p.parent;
        nodes.push(p);
    }
```

As each node that has a parent has an attribute containing its parent object, this will get you every node upstream of the selected node. The mouseovered node is selected too, which will allow us to select the links.

To style the nodes now is easy, simply see if the node's datum is located in the array of nodes we just created:

```
  node.filter(function(d) {
        if(nodes.indexOf(d) !== -1) return true;
  }).style("fill","steelblue");
```

To color the nodes, we use a similar approach, but check to see if the target of each link is in our array of nodes:

```
  //color the links
  link.filter(function(d) {
     if(nodes.indexOf(d.target) !== -1) return true;
  }).style("stroke","orange");
```

*Has to be target - as only one path will terminate at each node, but several paths may originate at each node, this is why we need to push the original node's datum into the array*

[Here's](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/6d75b1ab444f5eda554e6bf8a1b4070b) a set up with just the upstream highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness: `ancestors()` **do** work, but you have to call it on the hierarchy, not on the selection:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    var filtered = node.filter(function(e) {
        return d.ancestors().indexOf(e) > -1
    });
    filtered.selectAll("circle").style("fill", "red");
    filtered.selectAll("text").style("fill", "red");
})
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/bb5be85d509eb7824e95d193c4fb6d27/e87fb16f8058f85719647dde561bff12f998361a